# Expected distance for a gaussian variable to its nearest integer.

Tags: probability

Consider a Gaussian variable with arbitrary mean and variance, $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. I am interested in its expected distance to its nearest integer : 
$$
E[|X - R(X)|]
$$
where $R(X)$ is the round function to $X's$ nearest integer. This expectation carries out as : 
$$
E[|X-R(X)|] = \sum_{n=-\infty, \ n\in Z}^{\infty} \int_{x\in (n-.5,n+.5)}|x-n|f_X(x)dx
$$
The normal steps would be plug in the $f_X(x)$ into the equation above, and go through lengthy evaluations. However, I am intimidated by this direction. Can someone propose a more intuitive and easier way?

Through Python simulation, the value is very close to 0.25, which is the same as the case for uniform distribution.

```
In [42]: import numpy as np

In [39]: x = np.abs(np.random.randn( 1000000) +.2) ; y  = [abs(xx - round(xx))  for xx in x] ; np.mean(y)
Out[39]: 0.25004576419884023

In [36]: x = np.abs(np.random.random( 1000000)+.8) ; y  = [abs(xx - round(xx))  for xx in x] ; np.mean(y)
Out[36]: 0.24987253271457252
```

The first case (39) is  normal distribution, and the second (36) is for uniform distribution.

Any input or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance-to-nearest-integer function can be written in a Fourier series

$$ |x - R(x)| = \dfrac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \dfrac{\cos( (4n+2) \pi x)}{(2n+1)^2} $$

Since $E[\cos(tX)] = e^{-t^2 \sigma^2/2} \cos(t\mu)$, you get

$$E[|X - R(X)|] = \dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{2}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty 
e^{-2 (2n+1)^2 \pi^2 \sigma^2} \dfrac{\cos((4n+2) \pi \mu)}{(2n+1)^2}$$

The exponential factors decay very rapidly.  For $\sigma = 1$ even the $n=0$ term is only about $5.4 \times 10^{-10} \cos(2\pi \mu)$.

Comment: wow, thanks Robert, can you give me any references on why we can write the distance-to-nearest-integer as a Fourier series?

Comment: Any text that develops the elementary theory of Fourier series, or  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave