# Explanation for the uniformity of the distance between a Gaussian variable to its nearest integer?

Tags: probability, geometry, uniform-distribution

earlier I asked the question [Expected distance for a gaussian variable to its nearest integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759282/expected-distance-for-a-gaussian-variable-to-its-nearest-integer) and got a good answer. The expected distance is highly close to $1/4$, which is very similar to the uniform case.

Then I went on examine the distribution of $|X-R(X)|$, where $R(X)$ is the nearest integer of the variable.

As user Did and leonboy pointed out, for $\sigma \rightarrow 0 $, the distance are concentrated. On the other side, for $\sigma \rightarrow \infty$, $|X-R(X)|\rightarrow UNIFORM(0,0.5) $

The computer simulation I ran implies the variance doesn't need to go to infinite  to see the uniformity. See the figures below.

My question is how fast does  $|X-R(X)|$ converge to uniform distribution with the increases of $\sigma$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your integral formula is not correct: $|X - R(X)| < \delta$ is not the same as $0 < X < \delta$.

Comment: "the distance between a Gaussian variable and its nearest integer has a uniform distribution in [0,0.5], no matter what the mean and variance are." Of course that's false (no need to do experiments, just ponder a little). Suppose the mean is zero and the variance is very small (much less than 1)

Comment: "intuitive explanation for such a simple conclusion" Which is the simple conclusion? How did you get those formulas?

Comment: // Question massively modified to take into account the remarks I posted as an answer. //

Comment: Hi, Did,I am very grateful for your help. I realized my original post was quite stupid, I modified it to make it more clear for other users. I am sorry if I did something wrong. Is there a better way of acknowledging your contribution? Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason for the tag [geometry] in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0 < y < 1/2$,  $|x - R(x)| = y$ if $x = n \pm y$ for integer $n$, with 
$\dfrac{d}{dx} |x - R(x)| = \pm 1$ there, so the PDF of $Y = |X - R(X)|$ is
$f_Y(y) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty (f_X(n + y) + f_X(n-y))$ where $f_X$ is the PDF of $X$.
By the [Poisson summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula),
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f_X(n+y) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{2 \pi i k y} \widehat{f_X}(k)$$
where in this case
$$\widehat{f_X}(k) = e^{-2 \pi^2 k^2 \sigma^2 - 2 \pi i k \mu}$$
Thus for $0 < y < 1/2$, 
$$ f_Y(y) = 2 + 4 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \cos(2\pi k y) \cos(2 \pi k \mu) e^{-2 \pi^2 k^2 \sigma^2} $$
The  term $2$ is the uniform distribution, and the others decay rapidly as $\sigma$ increases.

Comment: Thank you Robert, for answering and helping me with those two questions! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

To slightly sober some conjectures formulated in the post, note that, when $\sigma\to0$, $P(|X-R(X)|\leqslant\delta)$ converges to $1$ for every positive $\delta$ if $\mu=R(\mu)$ (that is, $\mu$ an integer) and to $0$ for every positive $\delta\lt|\mu-R(\mu)|$ otherwise.

But indeed, when $\sigma\to\infty$, $X-R(X)$ converges in distribution to the uniform distribution on $(-\frac12,\frac12)$.